The result of my implementation of KMeans is not consistent
I'm trying to implement a simplified version of KMeans clustering, but somehow, sometime the result is not consistent
import numpy as np
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class KMeans:
    def __init__(
        self,
        n_clusters,
        max_iter
    ):
        self.n_clusters = n_clusters
        self.max_iter = max_iter
    
    def _get_distance(self, x, cluster_location):
        """calculate the euclidean distance from each points to the clusters center
        """
        return np.linalg.norm(x[:,np.newaxis,:]-cluster_location, axis = 2)
        
    def fit(self, x:np.ndarray) -> None:
        """Steps for k-means clustering
        1. initiate cluster location
        2. calculate distance from each points to cluster point
        3. assign each points to a cluster
        4. update the cluster location using the mean of the associated points
        5. repeat 2-4 until convergence or max_iter reached

        Args:
            x (_type_): _description_

        Returns:
            _type_: _description_
        """
        self.x = x
        data_dim = x.shape[1]

        # 1. initiate cluster location
        cluster_locations = np.random.uniform(x.min(), x.max(), size=(self.n_clusters,data_dim))
        # print("initial:\n",cluster_locations)

        for _ in range(self.max_iter):
            # 2. calculate distance from each points to cluster point
            distances = self._get_distance(x, cluster_locations)

            # 3. assign each points to a cluster
            clusters = np.argmin(distances, axis=1)

            # 4. update the cluster location using the mean of the associated points
            for cluster in range(self.n_clusters):
                # Check if cluster has any points
                cluster_mask = clusters == cluster
                if np.any(cluster_mask):
                    cluster_locations[cluster] = np.mean(x[cluster_mask], axis=0)
                else:
                    # If cluster is empty, reinitialize with a random point
                    cluster_locations[cluster] = x[np.random.randint(x.shape[0])]                        

        self.cluster_locations = cluster_locations
        self.clusters = clusters
        return None

    def visualize(self, data, clusters):
        _, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(5,5))

        cluster_color = [(random.random(),random.random(),random.random()) for _ in range(self.n_clusters)]

        for cluster in range(self.n_clusters):
            to_plot = data[np.where(clusters == cluster)[0]]
            ax.scatter(to_plot[:,0], to_plot[:,1], color=cluster_color[cluster])
        ax.scatter(self.cluster_locations[:,0], self.cluster_locations[:,1], marker="x", color='r', s=30)

        plt.show()

This is how I used it
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

random_state = 42
n_samples = 100

x, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples, random_state=random_state)
my_kmeans = KMeans(3, 50)
my_kmeans.fit(x)
my_kmeans.visualize(x, my_kmeans.clusters)

Most of the times, it gives me a reasonable output, like this

But every several runs, it gives me something like this

Is there something I missed?

K-means with a random initialization actually doesn't have a deterministic result. I don't see anything you are doing wrong here, it is just a property of the algorithm. Compare Wikipedia on the standard K-means algorithm: The algorithm is not guaranteed to find the optimum.

There is nothing wrong in your implementation or results. In fact, it is as expected. In your code, you are using make_blobs() with random selection of Gaussian samples. The make_blobs() function draws samples from a special Gaussian mixture model.
As explained here in more detail, for the make_blobs() function, each cluster or component has equal probability of being sampled and the cluster centers can be either specified or in the case of your code randomly generated.

Have you tried setting seed values for all the packages that use random values?
Can you try this in your the file where you implemented kmeans?
seed_value = 42
np.random.seed(seed_value)
random.seed(seed_value)

